# Still empty json array even done append in Python

Tags: python, json

It seems my json array still empty even already append the data object.

My code

```
tweets_data_path = 'twitter_test_data.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.dumps(json.loads(line))
        print tweet
        tweet["sentiment"] = raw_input('provide input (sentiment): ')
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

pprint(tweets_data)
```

My data

```
{"created_at":"Sun Apr 16 02:00:14 +0000 2017","id":853427785339084800,"id_str":"853427785339084800"}

{"created_at":"Sun Apr 16 02:03:24 +0000 2017","id":853428582613475332,"id_str":"853428582613475332"}
```

Output

```
python twitter_update_sentiment.py
{"created_at": "Sun Apr 16 02:00:14 +0000 2017", "id": 853427785339084800, "id_str": "853427785339084800"}
provide input (sentiment): 1
{"created_at": "Sun Apr 16 02:03:24 +0000 2017", "id": 853428582613475332, "id_str": "853428582613475332"}
provide input (sentiment): 2
[]
```

Comment: You just remove the `json.dumps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tweet` is a string, you can't use it as a dictionary, you have to use `json.loads`:

```
tweet = json.loads(line) # no `json.dumps`
print tweet
tweet["sentiment"] = raw_input('provide input (sentiment): ') # error was here
tweets_data.append(tweet)
```

Currently the error is when you try to set a new field, but you use `try .. except` which goes to continue and you miss it completely. A step-through in the debugger would have solved it easily.

If you still want to use `json.dumps` use it AFTER you set fields in the dictionary.

Comment: …and if the OP haven't ignored all errors by using `except: continue`, he would know that from an error message.

Comment: i want to avoid u python. maintain the original format. thats i'm using json.dumps.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the following after this line,

```
tweet = json.dumps(json.loads(line))

tweet = ast.literal_eval(tweet)
```

Don't forget to import ast,

```
import ast
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is json.dumps returning the str(you might think it is dictionary).

```
import json

from pprint import pprint

tweets_data_path = 'tweets.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweet["sentiment"] = str(raw_input('provide input (sentiment): '))
    tweets_data.append(tweet)

pprint(tweets_data)
```